# Deletar intervalo de linhas python

Tags: python, arquivo, delete, linha-de-comando, sed

Pessoal estou quebrando a cabeça para deletar um bloco de linhas que tem um delimitador.
Eu queria por exemplo deletar o bloco1 ai ele apagava o delimitador inicial final e conteúdo entre as linhas.

Ex:

#bloco1
CONTEUDO
#bloco1

#bloco2
conteudo
#bloco2

Comment: Olá, Welles. Quando fizer a pergunta, seja mais específico para podermos gerar uma solução. Vou supor que o texto está num arquivo e que você quer retirar um bloco de texto com delimitadores. Reescreva a sua pergunta para deixar de mais fácil entendimento para quem for consultar depois, ok? Vou deixar uma resposta que acho que te atende.

Comment: Veja se essa alternativa não é mais simples https://ideone.com/UNZoKE .Observação o código comentado é o código que seria usado caso queira trabalhar com arquivos.

Answer (score -3):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria ler o arquivo linha por linha e armazenar cada linha em uma lista. Depois, você pode percorrer a lista procurando pelo delimitador inicial e final e, quando encontrar, usar a função `del` para remover o bloco de linhas da lista. Em seguida, você pode reescrever o arquivo com a lista atualizada.

Aqui está um exemplo de código em Python que faz isso:

```
def remover_bloco(nome_arquivo, inicio_delimitador, fim_delimitador):
  # Abrir o arquivo
  with open(nome_arquivo, "r") as f:
    # Lê o arquivo linha por linha e armazena cada linha em uma lista
    linhas = f.readlines()

  # Inicializa as variáveis que irão armazenar os índices das linhas do delimitador
  inicio_encontrado = -1
  fim_encontrado = -1

  # Percorre a lista de linhas procurando pelo delimitador
  for i, linha in enumerate(linhas):
    if linha.strip() == inicio_delimitador:
      # Se encontrar o delimitador inicial, armazena o índice da linha
      inicio_encontrado = i
    elif linha.strip() == fim_delimitador:
      # Se encontrar o delimitador final, armazena o índice da linha
      fim_encontrado = i
      # Sair do loop, pois já encontramos os dois delimitadores
      break

  # Verifica se os delimitadores foram encontrados
  if inicio_encontrado != -1 and fim_encontrado != -1:
    # Remove o bloco de linhas da lista
    del linhas[inicio_encontrado:fim_encontrado+1]

  # Reescreve o arquivo com a lista atualizada
  with open(nome_arquivo, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(linhas)
```

Para usar esta função, basta chamá-la passando o nome do arquivo, o delimitador inicial e o delimitador final como argumentos. Por exemplo:

```
remover_bloco("arquivo.txt", "#bloco1", "#bloco1")
```

Isso irá remover todos os blocos de linhas que tenham os delimitadores "#bloco1" no arquivo "arquivo.txt".